# Uniform convergence in probability of Poisson process continuous functions

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

Let $Z_1, \cdots , Z_n$ exponential random variables of parameter 1. Let $S_n = Z_1 + Z_2 + \cdots + Z_n$ $t \geq 0$, $N(t) = \operatorname{card}(i \geq 1, S_i \leq t)$

We know that for all $T > 0$: $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|N(\frac{tn}{n}) - t|$ converges to $0$ almost surely.

We consider $(Y_n)$ a sequence of random variables taking values in the space of continuous functions $C(\mathbb{R}^+, \mathbb{R})$ endowed with the uniform convergence norm on all compacts.

We also know that for all $T \geq 0$, $(Y_n(t), 0 \leq t \leq T)$ converges in distribution to $(Y(t), 0 \leq t \leq T)$ a continuous function of $C([0,T], \mathbb{R})$

I must show : $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}\left|Y_n(\frac{N(tn)}{n}) - Y_n(t)\right|$ converges in probability to $0$.

I have tried to write this.

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $A = \{ \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|Y_n(\frac{N(tn)}{n}) - Y_n(t)| \geq \varepsilon \}$

By union bound, we have : $$P(A) \leq P\left(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|Y_n\left(\frac{N(tn)}{n}\right) - Y\left(\frac{N(tn)}{n}\right)| \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{3}\right) + P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|Y(\frac{N(tn)}{n}) - Y(t)| \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{3}) +  P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|Y_n(t) - Y(t)| \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{3}).$$

I can majorate the third term by $\varepsilon$ because the convergence in distribution to a non stochastic term is equivalent to the convergence in probability.

For the second term, I am not sure. $\frac{N(tn)}{n}$ converges almost surely to $t$.
So for n big enough, I think I can majorate the quantity $ P(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|Y(\frac{N(tn)}{n}) - Y(t)| \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{3}) $ (because almost sure convergence is convergence is keeped with continuous functions.

For the first term, I do not find a way to majorate it.

Any help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle the first term is to notice that with very high probability, you can bound $\frac{N(tn)}{n}$ by a constant $C_{\epsilon}$ depending only on $\epsilon$ i.e $\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{N(tn)}{n} \geq  C_{\epsilon}t \right)\leq \epsilon$ . So, with probability $1-\epsilon$, $\underset{0\leq t \leq T}{\sup} \lvert \frac{N(tn)}{n}\rvert\leq C_{\epsilon}t$. So, the first term can be upper bounded in the following way
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\underset{0\leq t \leq T}{\sup} \lvert Y_{n}(\frac{N(tn)}{n})-Y(\frac{N(tn)}{n})\rvert \right)\leq \mathbb{P}\left(\underset{0\leq t \leq C_{\epsilon} T}{\sup} \lvert Y_{n}(t)-Y(t)\rvert \right)$$ using the convergence in law allows you to bound this term.

Comment: Thanks. I can now continue the question.